Avoid memory use by text labels in PySpark's Levenshtein distance calculation
I have a pandas Series of 30,011 text ID labels of up to 20 characters each.  These
are manually typed, so there are many typos and creative embellishments applied
on an inconsistent basis.  I plan to calculate all pairwise Levenshtein distances
to feed a clustering algorithm and see if it identifies groups of labels that
likely correspond to the same ID.  Looping through each pair and using the
Python Levenshtein function
takes 1.5 hours to calculate 250+ million distances.  To make it manageable, the
distances are amassed in a 2D NumPy array of uint8.
I've dabbled in PySpark, so I wanted see if it would speed up the
calculation.  I followed this simple
example
and found that I needed first to cross-join the list of labels with
itself, then generate the distances:
+----------+------------+-----------+
|dict_words|  test_words|levenshtein|
+----------+------------+-----------+
|   absence|     absence|          0|
|   absence|     abcense|          2|
|   absence|     absance|          1|
|   absence|  acceptable|          7|
|   absence|  acceptible|          7|
|   absence|accidentally|          9|
|   absence|  accidently|          7|
|   absence| accidentaly|          8|
|   absence| contraversy|         10|
|   absence|     fullfil|          7|
|acceptable|     absence|          7|
|acceptable|     abcense|          6|
|acceptable|     absance|          7|
|acceptable|  acceptable|          0|
|acceptable|  acceptible|          1|
|acceptable|accidentally|          5|
|acceptable|  accidently|          6|
|acceptable| accidentaly|          5|
|acceptable| contraversy|         10|
|acceptable|     fullfil|          9|
+----------+------------+-----------+

The problem is that the 1st two "key" columns take much more memory
than the distances themselves, which were already hard to manage.  Is
there any way to leverage the parallel processing of PySpark without
incurring this overhead?
